# UEFI code for arm64-based Ubuntu cloud-images

Tags: uefi, cloud-init, arm64

I am doing lots of work with VMs and love using cloud-images to spin up new VMs inside QEMU very quickly. I do have a couple of questions:

1. The current cloud-images documentation is good but at no point is there a link to the process (and code) used by Canonical to generated these daily images and upload them to the web site. I would love to be able to see this code (I assume its open-source) so I can understand the steps. I assume its debootstrap based but there are some nuances I would like to understand.
2. I seem to have issues getting the arm64 images to work on a couple of the Arm-based machines I have access too (and I have access to a few including my M2 based Macbook and AWS Graviton). The issue seems to always come down to the UEFI binary blob which (I assume) is included in the cloud image not working no a given machine when kvm acceleration is used. I can consistently get this to work if I disable kvm and use the QEMU UEFI image but this can be slow. So I guess I would like to understand what UEFI code is used in the generation of arm64-based cloud-images.

Thanks for any pointers!

Stephen